# Configure CNTLM for proxy requiring basic authentication

Tags: windows, proxy, authentication

I am using the Windows 8 Release Preview, but most of the apps aren't working for me, as my institute's LAN connection is proxy based, that requires basic authentication.

I need help in configuring CNTLM for bypassing the authentication.

.pls help me out..
Otherwise, please suggest any alternative means for this problem

Answer (score 2):

This guy claims to have modified CNTLM to support basic auth:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1396749
(I haven't verified that this works on windows personally (it works fine on my linux))

I use polipo for the same purpose, and it seems to work fine on windows (at least for http connections, dunno about https)

Answer (score 1):

it works, cntlm segfaults with libc2.17 though, so make sure you're using libc2.16 or earlier