# Is there a software that can act as a "proxy repeater"

Tags: networking, proxy

Sorry for the vague title, I don't know what it's called, if even possible.

So where I am, all internet connections need to go through a HTTP proxy server, which requires authentication.
I'd like to know if there is a program that is able to connect and authenticate with the server, then act as a proxy server itself (Running on localhost:8080). When I want an application to connect to the internet, I would set the proxy settings to localhost:8080, and I would not have to enter in my credentials.

Like a way to route connections through a authenticated proxy server.

Basically, I don't want to have to enter my proxy credentials for every application that needs to connect to the internet. Also some applications don't encrypt the password, which kinda annoys me

[image: Diagram]

Currently I'm using PuTTY to connect to my VPS (which isn't blocked), to create a SOCKS proxy. Then using ProxyCap, I would set the applications to connect to localhost:1080 (SOCKS proxy). However networks speeds feel slow, and I'm concerned about my VPS' "bandwidth".

I cannot directly connect to the proxy server through ProxyCap because I believe ProxyCap itself hasn't authenticated with the proxy server (and there is no option or setting to configure)

If I use aria2 (for example).

- When connecting directly to the HTTP proxy server (Password is stored in plaintext!!!) I can get DL speeds from server X of at least 1.5MBs
- When doing the above (PuTTY -> SOCKS -> ProxyCap) I only get about 300KBs

Comment: A proxy, by definition, is a repeater.

Comment: Similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/431316/configure-cntlm-for-proxy-requiring-basic-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any proxy which supports "upstream" proxy can act as repeater.
Try [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). It supports parent proxy as well as authentication.

Comment: Squid works well, except I can't have directories with whitespaces in them, which may pose to be a problem (#WindowsXP -> "Documents and Settings")

Thanks anyway, I'll have a look at nwinkler's suggestion now

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to put it in "Documents and Settings"?

Comment: Well I don't really want to put it in the root of the drive.
And also permissions.

Comment: You can put it any folder as long as its path doesn't contain spaces. And it Only read write permissions in its folder.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) for this exact purpose with a proxy that uses NTLM authentication (Windows domain). It's pretty easy to set up, runs as a Windows Service, and your password is saved encrypted.

You can download the latest installer here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/cntlm/cntlm%200.92.3/

A guide for installing and configuring it can be found here: http://scottoffen.com/2013/10/29/solving-proxy-problems-with-cntlm/

I found Cntlm a bit easier to use than Squid. Squid provides more functionality, but you probably won't need that if you're only looking for the proxying part.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about what to put in the Domain setting, could you explain?

Comment: Ah, It looks like the proxy server only uses Basic authentication. Any other ideas apart from Squid?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you need?

Comment: Cntlm supports NTLM authentication for Windows domains. It might not be what you need - I didn't see any more specifics in your question.

Comment: Well when authenticating normally, I'd only enter in the proxy server, port, username and password. So regarding the Domain, I'm stumped.

Comment: It looks like the standard version of Cntlm does not support Basic Auth out of the box: http://sourceforge.net/p/cntlm/feature-requests/45/ - sorry.